# Does a procedure with heavy calculation in ASP.NET C# run on the client of server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started my first ASP.NET project, so I am probably missing some fundamentals. Part of the project involves a procedure(s) that runs a simple genetic algorithm with some user data which requires a lot of CPU resources.

1)  Does the procedure (at aspx.cs) run on server or client?
2)  In case it runs on the server, is there a way to run this at the client?

I googled this question and I think it runs on the server (like most code), but I'm not entirely sure. It's important to not hog the server too much, hence the second question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It runs on the server. There is no good way to move it to the client.

Comment: If you want it to run on the client it would have to be translated to javascript and sent to the browser.

Comment: almost all c# code you wrote are running on server. If server load is an issue then you are probably better off learning asp.net {core} MVC + JavaScript

Comment: If it is simple algorithm it shouldn't taken much cpu resources. How you are measuring the execution with cpu usage..? Can you post the procedure and the volume of data you are trying to process inside that procedure for more clarity. And for your question executing it inside database server is the most prominent way and we shouldn't or can't process it in client.

Comment: @Sivaprasath Do you have any advise on how to measure CPU usage and what would be acceptable to be suitable for this solution? The algorithm is (roughly) an evaluation of 2000 arrays with 30 elements. This evaluation contains sorting the arrays and calculating their fitness (that part is rather simple) I'd post it, but I have it in VBA (I needed proof of concept first)